# java JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I have a JFormattedTextField with a DateFormat. the format is "ddMMyy". This format allows quick input.On focus lost i want the text in the field to change to LocalDate as that is easier to read:

Input: "200295". converting to LocalDate with getValue() gives the LocalDate of 20. February 1995. this is all well and good, to text that is "1995-02-25" (`LocalDate.toString()`).

When the field loses focus, i want the text displayed in the field to change into the `LocalDate.toString()` without the actual value of the field to change from 200295/ 20. feb 1995.

Is there any way to make a text overlay the field instead of changing the value/text of it?

sscce of what i have been thinking so far:

main class:

```
public class FormatDateTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {


        public void run() {
            new TheFrame();
        }


    });
}
}
```

Frame class:

```
public class TheFrame extends JFrame{

JPanel panel;
JPanel textPanel;

JFormattedTextField dateField;
JButton button;
JTextArea textArea;

DateFormat format;

public TheFrame() {

    button = new JButton("click");

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            //temporarily crates a date to be converted.
            Date date = (Date) dateField.getValue();
            LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

            // sends the different values of the textarea
            textArea.append("The value: " + dateField.getValue() + "\n");
            textArea.append("the Date: " + date.toString() + "\n");
            textArea.append("the LocalDate: " + localDate.toString() + "\n");


        }
    });


    //Sets the text to the localDate for prettyness
    button.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
            Date date = (Date) dateField.getValue();
            LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
            dateField.setText(localDate.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
            dateField.setText("");

        }
    });


    textArea = new JTextArea();

    panel = new JPanel();
    textPanel = new JPanel();

    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    textPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //datefield and format
    format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy");
    dateField = new JFormattedTextField(format);


    textPanel.add(textArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(dateField,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(textPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pack();
    setSize(400, 300);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `JPanel` with a `CardLayout`. Put two components in it - the input field and the properly formatted one (I assume a `JTextField` would do).
On focus to any of them, bring the formatted field to front (using methods on the `CardLayout`), and let the user input her data. On focus lost, process the value (remember to deal with errors!) and, if parsing goes well, put the properly formatted value in the `JTextField` and bring it to the front.

-- UPDATE based on remark --

Lightweight solution: Use a `JLabel` instead of a `JTextField` for the formatted part. Just remember to call `setFocusable(true)`.

Even Lighter: Subclass `JTextField`. Override `paintComponent` such that: a) When the component is focused, delegate the drawing to `super`. b) When not focused, paint the properly formatted text yourself.

Comment: That would be an extreme workaround as there are many more fields on the panel i would like this for.

Comment: It works quite well until the user goes back to the textfield. The issue comes down to: on focusGained turning the LocalDate string back to the input format(ddMMyy) and set that as the text.

Comment: Added lighter weight solutions.

Comment: @Seagulltown - that would work, but you said "instead of changing the value/text of it"....

Comment: I will try your updated solution tomorrow. it sounds promising.